# Android facebook auth using Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

How can I use installed Facebook app to authorize silently to post messages? I mean I've seen many examples with authorization dialogs, but is it possible to use installed facebook app to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems it was a bug or don't know what. This worked for me:

```
public void loginToFacebook() {
mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

if (access_token != null) {
    facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
}

if (expires != 0) {
    facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
}

if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
    facebook.authorize(this,
            new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
            new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Function to handle cancel event
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // Function to handle complete event
                    // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token",
                            facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires",
                            facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError error) {
                    // Function to handle error

                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                    // Function to handle Facebook errors

                }

            });
}
}
```

from here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/